# How to generate castor for XML attribute value

Tags: castor

I am new to castor mapping, can any one suggest me how to write castor for below xml.

```
<Amt >
    <CustAmt Ccy="USD">35.47</CustAmt>
</Amt>
```

Specially I am looking for the mapping of attribute value. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
<class name="mypackage.OrderItem" auto-complete="true">
   <map-to xml="Amt" />
   <field name="custAmt" type="double">
      <bind-xml name="CustAmt" node="element" />
   </field>

   <field name="ccy" type="string">
       <bind-xml name="Ccy" node="attribute" location="CustAmt" />
   </field>
</class>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <class name="mypackage.OrderItem">
        <map-to xml="Amt" />
        <field name="ccy" type="string">
            <bind-xml name="Ccy" node="attribute"/>
        </field>
        <field name="custAmt" type="double">
            <bind-xml name="Amt" node="text" />
        </field>
 </class>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue